# Prove that $T(K) = a\ \mathrm{trace}(K)$ if $T(XY)=T(YX)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $T: M_{n,n}(\Bbb R) \to \Bbb R$ be a linear transformation such that $T(XY)=T(YX)$ for any two $n\times n$ matrices $X,\,Y$. How do you prove that $T(K)=a\ \mathrm{trace}(K)$ for some scalar $a$ in $\Bbb R$ for every $K$ in $M_{n,n}(\Bbb R)$?

I know that $\mathrm{trace}(XY)=\mathrm{trace}(X) + \mathrm{trace}(Y)$. My guess is that $\mathrm{trace}(XY)$ must be proportional to $T(XY)$, but I don't know how to state this mathematically.

Comment: $\mathrm{trace}(XY)$ is **not** $\mathrm{trace}(X)+\mathrm{trace}(Y)$ in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider when $X$ and $Y$ are matrices of the form $E_{i,j}$ which is the matrix with a one in the $(i, j)$-entry, but zeroes elsewhere. Find out what $E_{i,j}E_{k, l}$ is (there are some possibilities depending on whether the indices are distinct and so on). From this you should be able to derive $T(E_{i,j})$ for every $i, j$ which will allow you to conclude that $T(K) = a\operatorname{trace}(K)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you mean that $E_{i.j}$ has only one non-zero entry or that the ith row and jth column are filled with 1's?

Comment: I mean that there is only one non-zero entry. I will make that clearer.

Comment: Ok. But I still don't see how to go from $E_{i,j}E_{k,l}$ to the transformation T. I can see that Eij*Eji=Eii and Eji*Eij=Ejj.

Comment: If you've calculated what the matrix products are you should be able to deduce what $T(E_{i,j})$ is. Have you been able to do that? The easiest case to deal with is $T(E_{i,j})$ with $i \neq j$.

Comment: I can calculate the products, but I still don't get why these products would imply anything about the transformation. What is the connection between the transformation and the matrix products? I really can't see it :(

Comment: Well $\{E_{i,j} \mid 1 \leq i, j \leq n\}$ is a basis for $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$. A linear transformation is completely determined by its action on a basis. You say above you have calculated $E_{i,j}E_{j,i}$ and $E_{j,i}E_{i,j}$. What about $E_{i,j}E_{j,k}$ and $E_{i,j}E_{k,l}$?

Comment: I think I've got it. I proved that T(Eii)=a*trace(eii) for all i and that T(Eik)=a*trace(Eik) for all $i\neq k$. => Eij=a*trace(Eij) for all ij $1 \le (i,j) \le n$.

Comment: When you write $T(E_{i,i}) = a\operatorname{trace}(E_{i,i})$, what is $a$? How did you prove $T(E_{i,j}) = a\operatorname{trace}(E_{i,j})$? It isn't false, it just seems like a very strange way of saying it.

Comment: a is a scalar used to represent the fact that T(Eii) is porportional to trace(Eii).

Comment: You should be able to show that $T(E_{i,j}) = 0$ if $i \neq j$ and that $T(E_{i,i}) = T(E_{j,j})$ for all $i$ and $j$. The result then follows.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra condition on $T$ to ensure that $T$ is (a scalar multiple of) the trace :
$$
T(\text{diag}(x,0,0,\ldots,0)) = x
$$
This, together with @Michael Albanese's answer should do the trick.

Comment: I don't think you need this condition. All you need to know is that $T(E_{i,i}) = T(E_{j,j})$ which follows from what I put in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although probably not what you want, here is a proof from a higher perspective. $T(XY)=T(YX)$ implies that $T(XY-YX)=0$. Since the set of all matrix commutators over $\mathbb{R}$ is exactly equal to the set of all traceless matrices, the given property implies that
$$
T(A)=T
\ \underbrace{\left(A-\frac{\mathrm{trace}(A)}{n}I\right)}_{\text{traceless}}
+\frac{\mathrm{trace}(A)}{n}T(I)=\frac{\mathrm{trace}(A)}{n}T(I)
$$
and the result follows with $a=\frac{T(I)}{n}$.